# How can I force the size of long to 8-bytes on any arch?

Tags: compiler-construction, 64-bit, typedef, long-integer, sizeof

I want my long to be 8 bytes, regardless of whether I'm compiling in 32-bit mode or 64-bit mode. I am using MSVC and I don't care much about cross-platformity at this point. I tried doing things like

```
#define long __int64
```

or

```
typedef __int64 long;
```

but the first one results in massive compile errors in other files and the second one seems to be unacceptable by the compiler by itself.

Comment: That's not possible.  If you care about bit size then you should include stdint.h and use int64_t.  Using `long long` works today but may not work ten years from now.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't change the default behavior of a reserved type. a better practice is creating a new type if you like and work with it.

think on a case when you include the thirdPartyLib and it "h" file have something like that:

```
void func1(long number);
```

When your code includes the "h" file it will see the "number" parameter as 64bit BUT when the original "c" file of the lib included that "h" it can thinks that "number" is a 32bit. That will cause problems in the linkage stage.

Comment: All of my code is locked within a specific namespace, if I can make "long" work as "64-bit integer" only inside that namespace maybe I can avoid the problem you mentioned?

Comment: That might be a possibility, but I still believe a good practice would be to create a new type "myLong", "myInt64" or whatever which is 64bit. that's will also be less confusing for whom ever reads your code.

Comment: Or better yet, just work with `long long` which is always 64bit.

Comment: Well, I'm doing this, because I find "long long" extremely ugly and "myLong", "Long", "LONG", etc is no better.

Comment: I disagree, everything is better than taking something which have a known meaning and give it a different meaning in your own code. In the long run someone (may be even you) can miss the definition and expect the long to be 32bit on a 32bit machine.